# MVC Query doesn't fetch all records from the database

Tags: php, mysql, web

The DB stores several accounts: [winnie, winnie9, winnie10], however the query only returns one record when I fetch the data. What would be the solution?

Model method:

```php
protected function getApprovedUsers($login) {
        $sql = "SELECT `email`, `login`, `name`, `reg_date`, `pass`, `role` FROM `approved` WHERE `login` LIKE ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute([$login]);

        if($users = $stmt->fetchAll())
            return $users;

        return null;
    }
```

Controller call to the Model:

```php
    public function getCertainApprovedUser($login) {
        $users = $this->getApprovedUsers($login);

        if(is_array($users) || is_object($users)) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                return array("email"=>$user["email"], "login"=>$user["login"], "pass"=> $user["pass"],
                    "name"=> $user["name"], "reg_date"=> $user["reg_date"], "role"=> $user["role"]);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("Nothing to fetch");
        }
    }
}
```

Processing the data so that LIKE statement would work properly (%%):

```php
$record = $userContr->getCertainApprovedUser("%$login%");

$someJSON = array(
    [
        "login"=>"{$record['login']}",
        "email"=>"{$record['email']}",
        "name"=>"{$record['name']}",
        "reg_date"=>"{$record['reg_date']}"
    ]
);

$newJSON = json_encode($someJSON);
echo $newJSON;
```

Comment: Because your return is inside of your foreach in your controller. It will only go through one iteration of the loop. Instead, use the foreach to build up an array, then return it once the foreach is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the method `getCertainApprovedUser()`, you are returning a value in the foreach. This breaks immediatly the loop at the first iteration.

Changes your loop to something like :

```
$result = []; // initialize an empty array
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // add a user to that array
    $result[] = array("email"=>$user["email"], "login"=>$user["login"], "pass"=> $user["pass"], "name"=> $user["name"], "reg_date"=> $user["reg_date"], "role"=> $user["role"]);
}
// return the array containing the users
return $result;
```

And then, to build your json, apply the same logic :

```
$someJSON = [];

foreach ($record as $user)
{
    $someJSON[] = [
        "login"=>$user['login'],
        "email"=>$user['email'],
        "name"=>$user['name'],
        "reg_date"=>$user['reg_date']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Haven't noticed that at all!